# Why does Visual Studio's Publish Web feature intermittently fail to copy all changed files

Tags: visual-studio

For years now, across multiple versions of Visual Studio, there has been a bug with the Publish Web command (the one you get when you right-click on a web app and click Publish).

Very intermittently (about 10% of the time), some files that have changed will not be deployed if they already exist in the output directory. This is highly disturbing behaviour as you can never be confident that all your changed files have been copied to the destination correctly. The only workaround I know is to totally clear out the destination directory but this is a big hassle.

Does anyone else experience this issue? What could be the cause? Are there any known workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this too.  And yes, it is disturbing.  Especially since we seem to have to wait 2 years for any Visual Studio updates.

The only workaround I found was to check up some of my changed ASPX files, and verify that they changed, and if not, I select the Delete all files option in Publish to force a complete rebuild (slow and tedious).